# Animator Trigger Not firing on having error "parameter does not exist"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation

I am new to unity so i am unable to figure out this , I have dolphin in my game when it collides it dies so it has two animations one is its moving changes to dead body and second animation is bubbles which are dolphin's child object , the second trigger it fires is to stop bubbles , the first trigger is working that is its moving body changes to dead body , but the second trigger doesn't work that is its bubbles are still coming out, i dot know whats wrong.

```
public class Dolphin : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool IsDead=false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float upforce = 200f;
    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (IsDead == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, upforce));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        IsDead = true;
        anim.SetTrigger("Die");
        anim.SetTrigger("StopBubble");

        Debug.Log("rigger");             
    }  
}
```

[image: Animation 1]

[image: Animation 2]

Answer (score 1):

You should set the second trigger to your bubble game object Animator (Not to Dolphin Animator)

Only change your script to this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  IsDead = true;
  anim.SetTrigger("Die");
  transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("StopBubble");

  Debug.Log("rigger");             
}
```

(**Note:** Your bubble game object is the first child of dolphin game object. By using `transform.GetChild(0)` you can access to it)

I hope it helps you

Comment: Changing Script didn't work i am confuse about one thing as i am new , i haven't made the animations one one place these are two different animations on dolphin and  bubble even bubble is dolphin's child, Is it possible to still use one animator "anim" for them in script?

Comment: @AqsaNadeem As you say, you should have two Animator and you can't set bubble animation with Dolphin animator. I changed the code to get bubble animator and set trigger for it. What the error after you changed the script?

Comment: I think found your problem. did you add the bubble AnimatorController to Animator Component?

Comment: Click on `Bubbles animation` game object. in Inspector window, in `Animator` component, add `bubble animation.controller` in `Controller` field; and use the above code.

Comment: what it this bubble animation.controller, The Name of my animation is bubble stop but if i try to drop my animation there its not letting me do so

Comment: You have 2 files like this: XXX.controller in the assets folder. One of them is for your Dolphin game object and other for Bubble game object. You should put this to Controller field.